# Enforcing that inputs sum to 1 and are contained in the unit interval in scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, encoding, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have three inputs: `x=(A, B, C)`; and an output `y`. It needs to be the case that `A+B+C=1` and `0<=A<=1`, `0<=B<=1`, `0<=C<=1`. I want to find the `x` that maximizes `y`. My approach is to use a regression routine in scikit-learn to train a model `f` on my inputs `x` and outputs `y`, and then use `numpy.argmax` on `f` to find `x_best`. How can I ensure that `x_best=(A,B,C)` sum to 1 and are all within the unit interval? Is there some special encoding I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then it is simply [quadratic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) - all the constraints you mentioned (both equalities and inequalities) are linear.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, can you please see my edit? I forgot to mention that all of the values have to be within the unit interval, which I think breaks your solution.